# infinite discrete abelian group

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am not too familiar with Fourier analysis, but I needed to use
a certain result. I would appreciate any assistance.

I was reading a literature in Foruier analysis and it said 
something like "Every infinite discrete abelian group $G$ contains 
a set $E$ which satisfies (Property A)."

I was wondering if someone could tell me what do they mean by 
discrete group here. I looked up Wikipedia and it said that 
it is a group with discrete topology and that every group can be given 
a discrete topology.

So is that mean that the $G$ above can actually be any infinite abelian
group? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a discrete group is an arbitrary group equipped with the discrete topology. This is often done when another group with a nontrivial topology is likely to show up, as will certainly happen in Fourier analysis, essentially because the Pontryagin dual of a discrete group is in general not discrete.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!